# regex, how to exlude search in match

Tags: python, regex

Might be a bit messy title, but the question is simple.
I got this in Python:

```
string = "start;some;text;goes;here;end"
```

the *start;* and *end;* word is always at the same position in the string.
I want the second word which is *some* in this case. This is what I did:

```
import re
string = "start;some;text;goes;here;end"
word = re.findall("start;.+?;" string)
```

In this example, there might be a few things to modify to make it more appropriate, but in my actual code, this is the best way.

However, the string I get back is `start;some;`, where the search characters themselves is included in the output. I could index both **;**, and extract the middle part, but there have to be a way to only get the actual word, and not the extra junk too?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you need regex for this though?

Comment: Not for the example I made up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for regex in my opinion, but all you need is a capture group here.

```
word = re.findall("start;(.+?);", string)
```

Another improvement I'd like to suggest is not using `.`. Rather be more specific, and what you are looking for is simply anything else  than `;`, the delimiter.

So I'd do this:

```
word = re.findall("start;([^;]+);", string)
```

Comment: aw.. parenthesis, I feel so stupid now. No, regex is not needed here, but this is just an example. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, if it answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the answer.